# Can two Linux kernel timer handlers get executed at the same time?

Tags: timer, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing a kernel module with timers as below,

```
timer1_callback(){
    // task of timer1
}

timer0_callback(){
    while(1){
        // Do some input processing
        if (condition){
            Update timer1 to fire in 15 seconds from now
        }
    }
}

module_init(){
    //Initialize timer0 to fire in 1 second.
    timer_setup(&timerl0, timer0_callback, 0);
    mod_timer(&timerl0, jiffies + msecs_to_jiffies(1000));

    //Initialize timer1 to fire in 15 seconds. 
    timer_setup(&timerl1, timer1_callback, 0);
    mod_timer(&timerl1, jiffies + msecs_to_jiffies(15000));
}
```

I have initialized the timers as above. In this setup, timer0 will be in an infinite loop, waiting for some inputs (from the input event subsystem). According to that input, if a condition is met, timer1 will be updated to fire in 15s from that point onwards.

When I executed the above system, timer1_callback did not get executed at all. Even when the condition is met, it did not fire after 15s.

Are the separate timers get executed in separate threads or in a single thread?
Why the second timer never got triggered?

Comment: while(1) uses 100% of CPU Nothing same or lower priority runs.

Comment: Each CPU has a queue of timers sorted by time of expiry. Normally, the timer callback function runs on the last CPU that called `mod_timer` on the timer.

Comment: Infinite loop in the interrupt context is ingenious!